# CSS - How to place absolute div correctly

Tags: html, css, position, border, absolute

I have the following code:

```css
.menu{
 border: solid red; 
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 width: 60px;
}

.dropdown{
 position:absolute;
 background-color: grey;
 width:100px;
}

.dropdown ul{
 list-style:none;
 padding:10px;
 margin: 0;
}

.zoom{
  zoom:300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu zoom">
  Click me
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I place my dropdown menu to the same x position as the parent, without removing the border? I already tried 'box-sizing: border-box', but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure `.menu` has the `position: relative;` property

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: relative` on parent element and on child set position left to same negative value as left border width of parent element.

```css
.menu {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  left: -1px;
}
.dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.zoom {
  zoom: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu zoom">
  Click me
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But somehow on different zoomlevels the dropdown menu i now too far to the left. On my website it is very clear.

Comment: I am not sure, i tested it on chrome and firefox and it looks fine.

Comment: It is more clear on my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278579/css-how-to-align-an-absolute-div.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the **parent** as `positon:relative` and giving the **child** `position:absolte` with `top:100%;` and `left:-1px` ( **where -1 is taken because the width of border is 1 from left**)

> Here is the working snippet:

```css
.menu {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  left: -1px;
  top:100%
}
.dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.zoom {
  zoom: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu zoom">
  Click me
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```